# view list of images like a image gallery view in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

I have a list of images, which I need to show as an image gallery view style. I searched a lot but didn't find any answers.I tried it using a listbox but its doesn't look like an image gallery view style.If any body know how to do that or can provide me any suggestion or link will be a help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very good article with a very detailed description, examples and the source code. This is one of the best articles about images gallery in WP.

[Picasa_Image_Gallery_with_JSON_in_WP7](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Picasa_Image_Gallery_with_JSON_in_WP7)

Comment: thanks for reply but what I actually want is, when user view images in sliding manner, the of swapping images i.e. from one image to next image should look like gallery style of view images. It should work as gallery. I tried your answer earlier but its not working for me.

Comment: You want to create animation for scroll through images? Sorry, maybe I did not understand your question.

Comment: it should be me who should say sorry to you . I was not clear earlier. Yeah I want animation when user scroll the images left and right or vise versa.